# How to access third party content provider

Tags: android

I need to execute this three blocks of code without getting a SecurityException.

Google Play suggestion provider:

```
SearchRecentSuggestions query = new SearchRecentSuggestions(getActivity(),
                "com.google.android.finsky.RecentSuggestionsProvider", SearchRecentSuggestions.QUERIES_PROJECTION_DATE_INDEX);
        query.clearHistory();
```

Google Maps search history provider:

```
SearchRecentSuggestions query = new SearchRecentSuggestions(getActivity(),
                "com.google.android.maps.SearchHistoryProvider", SearchRecentSuggestions.QUERIES_PROJECTION_DATE_INDEX);
        query.clearHistory();
```

YouTube suggestion provider:

```
SearchRecentSuggestions query = new SearchRecentSuggestions(getActivity(),
                "com.google.android.youtube.SuggestionProvider", SearchRecentSuggestions.QUERIES_PROJECTION_DATE_INDEX);
        query.clearHistory();
```

I am getting this exception with any of those providers:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.finsky.providers.RecentSuggestionsProvider from ProcessRecord{451afbb0 16510:org.proverbio.history.cleaner/u0a230} (pid=16510, uid=10230) that is not exported from uid 10033
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3279)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4839)
```

Comment: i m also getting same exception have u resolved?